# Attribute is not an attribute class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following three classes:

SingletonDrawer.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(SingletonAttribute))]
public class SingletonDrawer : PropertyDrawer{

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label){
    }
}
```

SingletonAttribute.cs:

```
using UnityEditor;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
[System.SerializableAttribute]
public class SingletonAttribute : PropertyDrawer {
    public System.Type type;
    public SingletonAttribute(System.Type type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}
#endif
```

TimeTravel.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Simple.TimeTravel {
    [SingletonAttribute(typeof(TimeTravelController))]
    public abstract class TimeTravelController : MonoBehaviour {

    }

}
```

In my `TimeTravel` Class, I am trying to add `SingletonAttribute` Attribute, but I am getting the following error:

> 'SingletonAttribute' is not an attribute class [Assembly-CSharp] SingletonAttribute.SingletonAttribute(Type type)

What is it that I can do to attach that attribute to a class? Similar to `AddComponentMenu`, `DisallowMultipleComponent`, etc...

### Unity Example 1

Unity example of `DisallowMultipleComponent`

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {}
```

When you try to add two components of the same type (`MyClass`) to the GameObject, a window opens saying you can not do that.

### Unity Example 2

Unity example of `RequireComponent`

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {}
```

With this example when you add `MyClass` as a component to the GameObject unity will add the `Rigidbody` component if it isn't already on the GameObject.

### What I want to achieve

What I want to do is create an Attribute called `Singleton` or `SingletonAttribute` and when the user adds the component with that attribute it will look at the game scene and not add the component if it is already within the scene.

```
[Singleton(typeof(MyClass))]
class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {}
```

Comment: `SingletonAttribute` has to extend `Attribute` if it is to be used as an attribute.

Comment: Ahhh, it extends a System class, not a unity class...

Comment: Just a quick look at the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) indicates that `SingletonAttribute` should probably inherit from `PropertyAttribute`.

Comment: @mikez doing so, gives me this error: `The attribute 'SingletonAttribute' is not valid on this declaration type. It is valid on 'field' declarations only`

Comment: Ok. I think you should explain more what you are trying to do with unity. I am not being an expert in unity, but it appears you are trying to hook into a specific mechanism and not just asking a general question about how to declare attributes in C#.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example if that helps...

Answer (score 3):

Your custom attribute class must inherit from System.Attribute.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx

> You can create your own custom attributes by defining an attribute
>   class, a class that derives directly or indirectly from Attribute

Comment: Doing this removes the error, but it doesn't work run the `OnGUI` within unity.